# Trouble getting Mongoose to reconnect to nodes and send requests to secondaries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

A common connection string for mongoose connecting to a replica set is something like follows

```
var connection = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://db_1:27017/client_test,mongodb://db_2:27017/client_test", { 
    replSet : { rs_name : "rs0", poolSize : 5, socketOptions : { keepAlive : 1 } }
}, function(err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
});
```

The problem with that is if one of the two hosts is down, then it will fail to connect. If you only specify one host, then no requests end up getting sent to secondaries.

Here's my proof for that claim. If you specify one host, and setup your replica set so that there is one primary and an arbiter and then perform a query such as

```
myApi.find({}).slaveOk().read("s").exec(function(err, docs) { 
    console.log(docs) 
})
```

It will return results. Well, since I am specifying "s" (secondary), this query should throw an error because there are no running secondaries. In addition, if you bring the secondary online and then do `db.currentOp(true)`, you will never see any actual queries sent it's way.

The moment you alter the connection string to specify every host then you will see connections go to the secondary. The dilemma is that now, because you had to specify the additional host in the connection string, in the event a secondary was offline, it would fail to connect and we've now lost failover (or the entire point to replica sets)

I can't determine if this is a configuration mistake on my part, a bug in Mongoose, or a conceptual flaw in my understanding of the way replica sets function. From some of the docs, they seem to state that reading from secondaries is basically a bad idea, but the reason for doing so is usually issues with stale data. My issue doesn't have anything to do with stale date, I can't figure out a way to setup the system so that I can get queries to secondaries without losing failover capacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe I have solved all of my problems. Here is what I learned.

1. Specify all possible replica nodes in your connection string, otherwise Mongoose will never send requests there. Mongoose has a specific format for this which is different than the node-mongodb-native driver. Example below.
2. In order to prevent it from hanging forever if one of the nodes is down on bootup you need to specify `connectTimeoutMS` in the 'replset' options, then it will only wait that long for responses from each nodes on initial connection. If the node comes online at a later date, it will still be available.
3. The host name entries in your mongodb replica setup need to match the hostname entries in the connection string from your application and **all hostnames need to be accessible from all parties** (mongo to mongo and application to mongo). In my case I had aliased the hostnames from mongo to mongo as `mongo1:27017`, `mongo2:27017`, and `mongo3:27017`. My application server used a connection string with IPs. Mongoose was attempting to re-initate the connection using the `mongo1:27017` hostname (which my application server could not reach) rather than the IP address I specified in the connection string. This resulted in it never re-connecting to a node it lost contact with. It is possible had I used hostnames that the application could reach it still would have worked, but I think it's a best practice to make the connection string and the replica setup identical to remove possibly places for error.
4. On the mongodb node that you `rs.initiate()` you **might** need to update the hostname to be a value that all boxes (other mongodbs and application server can reach). By default it will likely end up with a hostname like `localhost`, which means something different on each machine. This can be from that boxes mongo shell like so.

Example:

```
// from mongo shell
conf = rs.conf()
conf.members[0].host = "mongo1:27017"
rs.reconfig(conf)
```

Final functioning connection string which successfully fails over between nodes, including throwing errors if a query is destined for a secondary but there aren't secondaries.

```
var connection = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://mongo1:27017/client_test,mongo2:27017/client_test,mongo3:27017/client_test", { 
    replset : { rs_name : "rs0", poolSize : 5, socketOptions : { keepAlive : 1, connectTimeoutMS : 1000 } },
}, function(err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
});
```

Working replica setup

```
{
        "_id" : "rs0",
        "version" : 4,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "mongo1:27017"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "mongo2:27017"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "mongo3:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : true
                }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.connection string just defines seed servers, mongodb driver tries to connect to these servers and get information about other servers in replicaSet( by calling rs.status()). You could have replicaSet with 5 nodes, but specify only one in connection string, but driver would be able to find four others if server from connection string is available.

2.My proposal is to use `secondaryPreferred` instead of just `secondary`, so that in case there is no secondary available, request would be done to primary.

Comment: That makes sense except if I specify one seed server, requests don't end up going to the secondary (regardless if I use `sp` or `s`). The usage of `secondary` was to prove this point as with no secondary up it should fail.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issue similar to yours while dealing with replica, in my case I had 1 primary node with a priority of 10, 1 secondary priority of 0(for analytics) and an arbiter.
My writes would fail after reconnecting the primary instance and I went through a lot trying to fix it here's the most important thing I learnt:

> When my primary is down or unreacheable, there has to be another member eligible to become primary.(At least 2members in my set has to have a priority >= 1).
>    If I have only arbiters, hidden, or members with a priority of 0,
>   queries will get stuck even after I reconnect my primary, my client is
>   unable to complete write queries. Read queries would still work, but
>   write wouldn't.

This is what I faced with mongoose, even with keepalive, autoreconnect and all the socket and connection timeout MS set.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @user3658423 I posted my answer inline above, are you facing similar issues? You can post a link to your question and I'll check it out.